# Android material tab bar and webview

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-studio

i found this project on internet : 
https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidMaterialDesignToolbar

It's a template for android in material design, i want to add different web view in each tab bar, when i try to add it gives me much syntax errors.
here is the code:

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    private WebView myWebView;
    private String LOG_TAG = "AndroidWebViewActivity";

    private int position;

    public static SampleFragment newInstance(int position) {
        SampleFragment f = new SampleFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, container, false);

        ProgressBarCircular progressBarCircular = (ProgressBarCircular) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
        fab.setDrawableIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.plus));


        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

                //enable Javascript
                myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                //loads the WebView completely zoomed out
                myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

                //true makes the Webview have a normal viewport such as a normal desktop browser
                //when false the webview will have a viewport constrained to it's own dimensions
                myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

                //override the web client to open all links in the same webview
                myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
                myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

                //Injects the supplied Java object into this WebView. The object is injected into the
                //JavaScript context of the main frame, using the supplied name. This allows the
                //Java object's public methods to be accessed from JavaScript.
                myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

                //load the home page URL
                myWebView.loadUrl("http://demo.mysamplecode.com/Servlets_JSP/pages/androidWebView.jsp");


                break;
            case 1:



                break;
            case 2:



                break;
            case 3:


                break;
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

i thought to put :

```
 myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

                //enable Javascript
                myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                //loads the WebView completely zoomed out
                myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

                //true makes the Webview have a normal viewport such as a normal desktop browser
                //when false the webview will have a viewport constrained to it's own dimensions
                myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

                //override the web client to open all links in the same webview
                myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
                myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

                //Injects the supplied Java object into this WebView. The object is injected into the
                //JavaScript context of the main frame, using the supplied name. This allows the
                //Java object's public methods to be accessed from JavaScript.
                myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");

                //load the home page URL
                myWebView.loadUrl("http://demo.mysamplecode.com/Servlets_JSP/pages/androidWebView.jsp");
```

in each "case" and change the url
but this is the errors that i get:

> Error:(33, 10) cannot find symbol method
>   setArguments(android.os.Bundle) Error:(39, 20) cannot find symbol
>   method getArguments() Error:(63, 48) cannot find symbol class
>   MyWebViewClient Error:(64, 50) cannot find symbol class
>   MyWebChromeClient Error:(69, 54) cannot find symbol class
>   JavaScriptInterface

Comment: Have you made MyWebViewClient and MyWebChromeClient classes?